# Cycles - Different render output when using CPU or GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When rendering a file on SheepIt I notided there is a difference between PNG images when the image is rendered with CPU or GPU only. I reproduced the same situation on my computer and got similiar results so the renderfarm does not cause the problem. Only changed the Device (GPU or CPU) setting in render properties.

I am new to Blender and was wondering if this is a known issue or did I just miss an important setting? For those that don't see it, I am talking about the grass particles. Left is GPU, right side is CPU.

[image]